# How to increment month var by 1 step in a batch file?

Tags: date, batch-file

I have written a rather small batch file that does some date calculations for me.

However, I have stumbled upon a minor problem:

Whenever I try to increment my month var, it simply sets the var to the desired incrementation.  Code:

```
: How much time should we add? Default is 1 month
SET timeadd=1

: Set the date variables to build needed format
SET YYYY=%date:~-4%
SET MM=%date:~3,2%
SET DD=%date:~0,2%

if not %MM%==12 (
    SET /A MM=MM+timeadd
    SET changed=1
)
```

After the declaration, the month var would today (August 17th) be "08".

After the if block however, this var would change to "1".

I could guess that this is a conversion problem (date beeing a string, timeadd beeing an integer), however I really have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: that's because numbers with leading 0 are treated as octal. 08 is not valid octal number, so you're left with 1

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought (and in the meantime since asking the queston found out, too).
Now the question remains for me, how I can work around this... any idea?

Comment: Found the solution after a hint from wmz (Thanks again mate).

Inserted the following code before the if statement solved the problem.

    if %MM% LSS 10 SET MM=!MM:~-1!

Comment: @AndréG Please consider posting the solution as an answer and accept it, so it can serve as future reference for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, this is happening because a leading `0` indicates octal notation (just like a leading `0x` indicates Hex notation), but the octal numbering system runs from 01 to 07, so there is no octal 08 or 09, rather it would be 010 and 011.

Decimal Value 8 == Octal Value 010

Decimal Value 9 == Octal Value 011

To verify this for yourself, type this at the command-prompt

```
c:\>set /a 010
c:\>set /a 011
```

Your output will be:

```
8
9
```

=======================================

My solution to this is simply to check for any leading `0`'s and delete them.

```
if "%MM:~0,1%"=="0" set MM=%MM:~-1%
```

Do any mathmatical magic I need done...

```
set /a MM=%MM% + 1
```

...and then add the leading `0`'s back on if necessary.

```
set MM=0%MM%
set MM=%MM:~-2%
```

Just remember to make sure that it doesn't exceed 12 (in this instance) or get lower than 1.